# How i can make WCF in C# for windows based System?

Tags: c#, html, wcf

i want to make a WCF application or [application] in c# for respond queries who i send through My HTML based application.

suppose i send a queries to url and they respond me for that by calling a TCP socet who already installed in the system of user.

can you tell me it's possible to call them locally through HTML. are they allow them to call.

Are i can make a application in HTML , css , javascript who call the WCF and WCF respond the queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF is a communication frame work that supports all of the scenarios you mention.  WCF is easily accessed from both web based technology and windows based. ]

### EDIT

One File no config WCF service.

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System;

[ServiceContract]
public interface  AddStuff
{
    [OperationContract]
    int Add(int X,int Y);
}

public class opAddStuff : AddStuff
{
    public int Add(int X, int Y)
    {
        return X + Y;
    }
}

public class Pgm
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string httpAddr = "http://127.0.0.1:6001/AddStuff";
        string netAddr= "net.tcp://127.0.0.1:5001/AddStuff";

        System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost SH = new ServiceHost(typeof(opAddStuff),new Uri(httpAddr));

        BasicHttpBinding B = new BasicHttpBinding();
        NetTcpBinding NB = new NetTcpBinding();

        SH.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(AddStuff), B, httpAddr);
        SH.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(AddStuff), NB, netAddr);



        System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = SH.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
       // If not, add one
        if (smb == null)
            smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();

        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;

        SH.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
        SH.AddServiceEndpoint(  ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,  MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),  "mex");

        SH.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Service at your service");
        string crap = Console.ReadLine();



    }
}
```

Comment: can you guide me how i can make that. means how to start for that

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple enough starting point http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/GettingStartedWithWCF.aspx.

If you like to immediately get started with code, create a new project of type "WCF Service application" in Visual Studio.  You'll then get the some skeleton service which you can run.  Right-click, the Service.svc file --> Browse.  The service "help" (a blue-themed) page will be displayed in internet exploere and voila you have a running wcf service.

The code for the service is in Service.svc.cs file and the contract implemented by the service is in the IService.cs file.